# Get domain names from IP addresses from access.log

Tags: apache-2.2, ip, domain-name, logging

Actually I want to see people from which domain access my website. I want to generate the domain names from IP addresses in the Apache access.log file.

How can I do this? There are around 54 log files. I concatenate all the files into one.

This is a Unix server. I have to use a apache log file analyzer. So i use webalizer but it is does not resolve IP to domain names.

Comment: Parsing Apache logs is a rather messy way to do this. Usually a solution such as Google Analytics will give you more reliable data.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a simple script for this a long while back. It's less than perfect and has a few failure modes, but does well enough for casual inspection. I've never been bothered to improve it, but perhaps someone else will.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read junk
do
        echo -n "$junk "
        dig +short -x $junk
done
```

Use it as such:

```
cut -f 1 -d ' ' access.log | sort | uniq | ips.sh
```

Comment: Sorry for asking this. I am pretty new with terminal commands and shell. I copied the script above in ips.sh and typed in the cut statement as shown. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Did you do `chmod +x ips.sh` ? You need to specify execution permissions

Comment: yes I did a chmod. It tells me "ips.sh: command not found"

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Windows you can parse the concatenated log file with a script, performing "nslookup" on each IP.

```
if wscript.arguments.count > 0
then
  logname = wscript.arguments(0)
  set fs = wscript.createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  set readstream = fs.opentextfile(logname, 1, 0, 0)
  while not readstream.atendofstream str = readstream.readline ' parse str with RegEx object to get IP
    set shell = wscript.createobject("wscript.shell")
    shell.run "nslookup " & ip & " > temp.txt", 0
    set lookupstream = fs.opentextfile("temp.txt", 1, 0, 0)
    lookup = lookupstream.readall ' parse lookup info
    lookupstream.close
  wend
  readstream.close
```

Comment: @MichaelHampton
`if wscript.arguments.count > 0 then
logname = wscript.arguments(0) 
set fs = wscript.createobject("scripting.filesystemobject") 
set readstream = fs.opentextfile(logname, 1, 0, 0) 
while not readstream.atendofstream 
str = readstream.readline 
' parse str with RegEx object to get IP 
set shell = wscript.createobject("wscript.shell") 
shell.run "nslookup " & ip & " > temp.txt", 0 
set lookupstream = fs.opentextfile("temp.txt", 1, 0, 0) 
lookup = lookupstream.readall 
' parse lookup info 
lookupstream.close 
wend 
readstream.close`

Comment: @VladimirTsuverkalov I added the script from your comments to the answer but it looks incomplete.  Did the comment box cut off the end of the script?

Comment: @Ladadadada I was just posting a general outline of a script, skipping parts that do the parsing itself. If it's desired, I can edit them in a bit later